# Recover last visited page from cache when Firefox went offline

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I am using Firefox 41.0.1 in Ubuntu 15.04. When I lose internet connection without noticing, then click on a link I'll get a "Server not found" message. Is there a way to go back to the previous page? The "go back" button doesn't work because Firefox tries to reload the page instead of using the cached content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Firefox add-on, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/cachemachine/, or this other one, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cacheviewer/.